# Best way to implement timeouts in java when making a HTTP request

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

Is it better to use the setSoTimeout on java.net.Socket or to wrap the service making the Http calls with another class with an ExecutorService and manage method timeouts with Futures?

Better is currently defined as good practice / more reliable / accurate. Not necessarily considering impact on performance unless it is considerable.

Edit: Should have also mentioned the  connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout) method on java.net.Socket to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BenG -- I think this is an "it depends on what you want" scenario -- if you normalize on the concurrency libs, that's fine, but you need to manage closing the socket yourself.

If you want to use the timeout, it'll do it for you.

If you are using the concurrency libs everywhere in your code and they feel really natural, sure, manually manage the socket yourself.

Technologically (if you look at the code inside of Socket) there isn't any big advantage to one or the other. Just make sure when you are handling your socket state in your Future, you are catching the potential IOExceptions so processing your future's doesn't potentially blow up your executing thread.

Comment: Technically there is a huge advantage to using a socket read timeout. It is one extra line of code that triggers a pre-existing feature in the kernel, plus a catch block, as opposed to starting another thread, with a thread stack which has its own cost, and a whole lot of custom code. Also the `Future` approach doesn't actually terminate the read of course.

Comment: @EJP, the timeout is just calling close() on the socket which calls down the kernel to do the actual socket close right? I wasn't sure if you were saying the timeout (the way it is implemented in the JDK today) is more magical than just invoking the methods yourself.

I absolutely agree it is less code and overhead in the running VM (per the reasons you gave), but just wanted to make sure there weren't two separate "close" code paths that were being executed here. From the code I read through, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Neither?  Use `HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout()` and `setConnectTimeout()`.

Comment: As HttpURLConnection uses the socket method(s) I mentioned, I assume you are advocating for using those methods. Can you elaborate as to why this is a better method?

Comment: @BenG - because you shouldn't generally be using sockets directly to do http.  there are a wealth of libraries out there which already do that.  the class i mentioned is part of the jdk.